# How can I make files HTTP addressable in Java?

Tags: java, file, http, ftp, server

I need a means of making files in a specific folder HTTP addressable with a Java server - e.g. files on the server's /etc/serverdata/images would be able to be accessed (preferably in a secure manner) at http://coolServer/serverdata/images by another Java application.

My alternative would be FTP, but HTTP addressing is preferred. If HTTP addressing won't work, why not?

Comment: So what did you try?  Why didn't it work?  What code/software did you use?

Comment: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-have-a-simple-http-server.html

Trying something like this, wondering if there is a better/more secure way.